Flutter Getx: Not able to navigate back when calling Get.snackbar()
I am not able to navigate back whenever I call the Get.snackbar() method using Getx. Only after the snackbar disappears I am able to navigate back. Is there any way to change this behaviour to let the user navigate back even when the snackbar is being displayed? Below is the code:
 SnackbarController snackbar({
    required String title,
    required String message,
    Color? bgColor,
    Color? textColor,
  }) {
    return Get.snackbar(

      title,
      message,
       snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
      backgroundColor: bgColor?? Colors.green,
      colorText: textColor??Apc.white,
      isDismissible: true,
      dismissDirection: DismissDirection.horizontal
              
    );
  }


I found the actual solution. I wrote the code to navigate back in the Popscope method using Get.back().Changing the navigate back statement from Get.back() to Get.back(closeOverlays: true) did the trick.By default the closeOverlays property is set to false.This property determines whether the method should close any overlays (like snackbars, dialogs, bottom sheets) that are displayed while navigating back.
Navigator.pop(context) will also work.The difference between the two is that pop() method will just navigate back without closing the overlay while Get.back(closeOverlays: true) will close all overlays and navigate back.

Remove SnackbarController first and only create a function like this
showSnackBar ({required String title, required String message, Color? bgColor, Color? textColor}){
  Get.snackbar(
      title,
      message,
      snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
      backgroundColor: bgColor?? Colors.green,
      colorText: textColor??Apc.white,
      isDismissible: true,
      dismissDirection: DismissDirection.horizontal

  );
}


Sorry but I have edited the question. The issue is that I am not able to navigate back when snackbar is being shown. The UI is still responsive. I tried adding your code but still didn't work.

Use WillPopScope for back Like this
        if (Get.isSnackbarOpen) {
          Get.back(); // Dismiss the snackbar
          return false; // Prevent the default back action
        }
        return true; // Allow the default back action
      },```

Thanks for the reply. I already found the solution. Actually the issue was with Get.back(). I replaced the statement with Navigator.pop(context) in Popscope method and now it's navigating back without any issue. Looks like Get.back() won't be suitable in this scenario.
